# How to delegate Magento 1=>2 migration to a 3rd party, without leaking PII?

Tags: security, magento2-migration-tool, gdpr

My company manages many Magento stores for our clients. Most things we do in-house, but migrating 100+ stores to 2.x on our own would take a lot of manhours, so we'd like to test some 3rd party vendors and see if they can do a quality job with less cost.

#### How can we prevent the PII from those stores leaking into the wrong hands?

We've never had to give a 3rd party access to the store database, so we've never faced this problem and aren't sure how to handle it.

#### We've thrown around ideas like:

1. **Anonymize the data first, let the 3rd party write the migration mappings, but run the migration script ourselves**
   not ideal; still lots of work for us; migrations might not actually work
2. **Encrypt all the customer data first, then decrypt it in the Magento 2 DB when we receive it.**
   Still lots of work, plus requires modifying DB to accommodate the longer, encrypted versions of those strings, will require 3rd party to understand what's happening there and apply the same schema change
3. **Anonymize the data first, then once we get the finished M2 DB back, write scripts to update those anonymized strings with data from the original M1 DB**
   I don't know if this can even work. Also seems like a lot of work: Basically like re-migrating.

#### How do *you* prepare for this sort of scenario?

Clarification, in response to comments:
**3rd party**: refers to a company who offers a paid service to migrate your Magento 1 store to Magento 2. Just [Google for "Magento 2 migration service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+2+migration+service) and you'll see what I mean.
**Who we are**: We're not *re-selling* a migration service. We manage many stores as a turn-key solution we provide to clients. They ship us merchandise in bulk, then we handle all the logistics of getting it sold online, and send them a check for their profits. Many of them don't even know what Magento is, much less what version their store uses.

Comment: Not possible imo, not very ethical either.

Comment: `nonymize the data first, then pull data from the Magento 1 DB to "fix" it later` is not   idea

Comment: what you  mean by 3rd party?

Comment: talking about which 3rt party?

Comment: in your word thirty mean  the company who will migrate your  store,magento 1 to magento2. Am i right?

Comment: @AmitBera I added clarification to the question.

Comment: @VivekKumar Can you elaborate on how this is an ethical issue? I clarified in the question what our role is in this arrangement.

Comment: if you will do legal bound with migration provider company  and if that company  has the good reputation`,encrypt all the customer data first, then decrypt it in the Magento 2 DB when we receive it` is possiable but lot of works need

Comment: "We're not re-selling a migration service" ,  I think that clears it up!
With all the encryption and decryption I think it will even cost you more than just doing it yourself.
Also magento migration tools may not with  work with your encrypted data  since it may change datatype of many tables.